# Generate swagger.json

Tags: java, swagger

I have a java project (tomcat webapp) with some REST Api. I want to generate swagger documentation for them. I started from this [tutorial](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/resteasy/swagger-quickstart-tutorial) ([github](https://github.com/fmarchioni/mastertheboss/tree/master/swagger-demo)). 
I don't have maven we use an ant task. I included swagger-annotations-1.5.0.jar and all jar that cames with swagger-jaxrs JAR 1.5.0 version( I can include a complete list if it is useful)
I've annotated some method and I have a configuration class like this:

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class Configurator extends Application {
public Configurator() {
    init();
}
private void init() {
    BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
    beanConfig.setVersion("1.0.0");
    beanConfig.setSchemes(new String[]{"http"});
    beanConfig.setHost("myserver.it:8080");
    beanConfig.setBasePath("/swagger-demo/api");
    beanConfig.setResourcePackage("myserver.rest");
    beanConfig.setTitle("RESTEasy, Swagger and Swagger UI Example");
    beanConfig.setScan(true);
}
```

}

when I deploy it agains tomcat 9 I can see this log in localhost.log file

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.swagger.util.Json.create()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper;
    at io.swagger.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider.(JacksonJsonProvider.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1375)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.createMe(ClazzCreator.java:272)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:366)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:83)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(Cache.java:97)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache.compute(Cache.java:199)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:122)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2126)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:116)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.AbstractHk2InjectionManager.lambda$getAllServiceHolders$0(AbstractHk2InjectionManager.java:160)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.LinkedList$LLSpliterator.forEachRemaining(LinkedList.java:1235)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.AbstractHk2InjectionManager.getAllServiceHolders(AbstractHk2InjectionManager.java:164)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.getAllServiceHolders(ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.java:54)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getServiceHolders(Providers.java:337)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getCustomProviders(Providers.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.initialize(MessageBodyFactory.java:238)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory$MessageBodyWorkersConfigurator.postInit(MessageBodyFactory.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.lambda$initialize$2(ApplicationHandler.java:372)
    at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.forEach(Arrays.java:3880)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:372)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.lambda$initialize$1(ApplicationHandler.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.(ApplicationHandler.java:282)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.(WebComponent.java:335)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:178)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:370)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:974)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4813)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5125)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3700)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.backgroundProcess(StandardContext.java:5447)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1400)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1400)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1368)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

If I try to reach http://myserver.it:8080/swagger-demo/api/ this give me 404 error.

I read this post about this error ([here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/1601)) but I really can't say what's wrong. I'm strugglin.
Any hints would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I answer to myself since I finally find a solution. Problem was inconsistency with libraries. I solved using this site [Jar download](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/io.swagger/swagger-annotations/1.5.0), that gives me all the dependencies. Then I compare some libraries that I already jave in my project and in caso of conflict I choose the newest one.

Comment: Why you need to download JAR if you can use maven?

Comment: as I said before, unfortunatly  we don't use  maven but an ant task, It would be a good idea to move to maven